# Equal space to the left and right of text in all navigation menu items

Tags: html, css, sass, flexbox

I'm using flexbox to create a navigation menu and I want to make sure the text to the left and right of each word are exactly even.

Right now, the boxes are perfectly even responsively, but when the characters of the word don't match others, the space around the words are no longer even.

Here's my fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/omarel/p204jjnr/2/

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 50px;
}
header .tab {
  color: #fff;
  width: 16.66%;
  height: 70px;
  border: 1px solid red;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 2.4vw;
  vertical-align: middle;
  line-height: 70px;
}
/* BORDER BOXING  */

header,
header .tab {
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="tab">home</div>
  <div class="tab">hello</div>
  <div class="tab">longer word</div>
  <div class="tab">short</div>
  <div class="tab">Neighborhood</div>
  <div class="tab">Floor Plans</div>
  <div class="tab">Views</div>
</header>
```

**UPDATE:**
The solution was a combination of answers below:
Both adding flex:auto and removing the width from  header .tab

Comment: I'm not sure I understand. If the tabs are all set to the same width, and some tabs have more text than others, then there is always going to be some difference in space around the text... no?

Answer (score 1):

Instead of setting a `width` for each item:

```
width: 16.66%
```

Let the width be auto (content-based) and use `padding`:

```
width: 16.66% <-- REMOVE
padding: 0 20px
```

Now, the space to the left and right of the text is consistent in all tabs.

Here's a simplified version of your code:

```css
header {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  position: fixed;
  background-color: #000;
  padding: 50px;
}
header .tab {
  padding: 0 20px;
  height: 70px;
  font-size: 2.4vw;
  color: #fff;
  border: 1px solid red;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div class="tab">home</div>
  <div class="tab">hello</div>
  <div class="tab">longer word</div>
  <div class="tab">short</div>
  <div class="tab">Neighborhood</div>
  <div class="tab">Floor Plans</div>
  <div class="tab">Views</div>
</header>
```

### [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/p204jjnr/5/)

Comment: yes!!! that did it, but it only worked along with the answer below about adding flex: auto

Comment: The answer should work fine as-is. Not sure what `flex: auto` adds. Check the demo I included.

Answer (score 1):

For flexbox you use the flex property to specify your elements length. Look into flex-basis, flex-shrink, and flex-grow. Remove the width and set your flex to auto;

```
header .tab{
    color: #fff;
    flex: auto;
    height: 70px;
    border: 1px solid red;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 2.4vw;
    vertical-align: middle;
    line-height: 70px;
}
```

Comment: I combined your solution along with removing the width and it worked so it was a combo of your answer and removing the width. Thank you so much!

Comment: I said remove the width in my answer ;), but glad it worked out!